# Directory folder not unique in the URL problems (with .html extension removal)

Tags: .htaccess

I have my rewrite rules to remove the .html extension. Works fine, apart from one specific .html file, which has the same name as the directory its in. In other words, The directory folder is not unique in the URL, eg test/test.html.

This causes the browser to show the directory structure instead of redirecting to the file.

Anyone know a workaround for this?

My .htaccess file is currently:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Thanks

Dev

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews`. Also could you expand on what url doesn't work, and what the result is you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

Not So Sure Try.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule /test/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Comment: OK thank you, I will give it a go this week and come back to you.